# In what branch should I be when doing a rebase?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, rebase, git-rebase

I have a `master` branch with some commits that the branch `development` doesn't have.

The `development` branch has even more commits that `master` doesn't have.

I want to merge the state of `development` to `master`, i.e. override whatever changes `master` has that `development` lacks.

I have been told that I should a rebase. [When I read about rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), I understand that the syntax is the following:

```
git rebase master
```

**What I don't understand though, is from what branch I should write the command (to accomplish the described scenario), in `master` or in `development`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific scenario, you would write the `rebase` command from the `development` branch.

This is similar to how `git merge master` would merge master onto your current branch.

Comment: Ah, OK. So doing a rebase means that I continue my state on `development` while doing changes to "the past" (in `development`)? Then to merge the two branches, I still have to do a merge from `master`?

Comment: Yes, `development`'s history is moved on top of `master`'s history. So `development` has `master`'s commits but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout development and rebase from there as so:

```
git checkout development
git rebase master
```

The latter example, `git rebase master development` is a shorter version of the commands above (as described in the documentation you had linked).

This will cause your development branch changes to seem as if they started from the latest commit on master (provided you don't run into any conflicts, which you'll have to resolve during a rebase if you come across them). If all goes well you will be able to then merge development into master which will act as a simple fast-forward merge.

See http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/rebasing.html for a good explanation.